# I'm trying to write a specific output that can be used with influxdb

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, parsing

I have the below data:

```
Boat 1, DateTime=   1601554200  Lat=    41.47823666666667   Lon=    -71.334355
Boat 1, DateTime=   1601554260  Lat=    41.47823666666667   Lon=    -71.33435833333333
Boat 1, DateTime=   1601554320  Lat=    41.47823833333333   Lon=    -71.33436166666667
```

I am currently using pandas output to CSV but am struggling to remove some of the spaces so that it is output like below:

`Boat 1,DateTime=1601554144 Lat=41.47823833333333 Lon=-71.33435833333333`

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Comment: Is your "below data" a text file?

Comment: Please show an example of what you've done, i.e. your code.

Comment: @richardec - I currently have a dataframe that I am using the below code to try and turn into the data format I am after. `Tester.to_csv('Mk1.csv', header = None,  index = False, sep = '\t',quoting= None, doublequote = False)`

Comment: Update your post with the output of `df.head()`.